# Corrigir o erro syntax highlight de JavaScript para template strings?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, syntax-highlighting

Atualmente, há um erro no *syntax highlight* de JavaScript quando são usados os *template literals*. Por exemplo:

```js
$('.parent').on('click', '.trigger', function() {
  console.log(`Botao clicado: "${$(this).text()}".`);
});
```

Uma imagem do problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há planos para corrigir isso?

Comment: Se isso depender da SE, esquece. É igual governo.

Comment: Segundo [este FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/401803), o site usa o [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) pra fazer o syntax highlighting, e eles tem [essa issue](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/492) aberta (desde 2017). Então acho não é a SE que vai arrumar (se nem os problemas dela ela arruma, imagina o de outros...)

Comment: Faz sentido mudar isso para `[status-pronto]`? Creio que tenha sido corrigido [com a introdução do highlight.js](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401031/8839059)

Comment: @RafaelTavares, boa observação, creio que sim. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse problema *provavelmente* foi corrigido pela introdução do **highlight.js** substituindo o Google Prettify. Uma explicação completa pode ser encontrada no comunicado oficial: [Goodbye, Prettify. Hello highlight.js! Swapping out our Syntax Highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/818993).

O principal motivo da mudança foi pelo fato do Google Prettify ter sido [descontinuado em Abril de 2020](https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify/commit/e006587b4a893f0281e9dc9a53001c7ed584d4e7), além de não ter tido um desenvolvimento constante no período recente anterior ao encerramento.

A introdução do highlight.js no SOpt e aqui no Meta ocorreu no dia 24 de Setembro de 2020.

Os bugs desse *syntax highlighter* podem ser publicados como resposta no [post já mencionado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/818993).